# I don't understand when to use pointers on go

Tags: go

I am doing a tour of go language, and I have a question about pointers.

Example code (https://tour.golang.org/methods/19):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type MyError struct {
    When time.Time
    What string
}

func (e *MyError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("at %v, %s",
        e.When, e.What)
}

func run() error {
    return &MyError{
        time.Now(),
        "it didn't work",
    }
}

func main() {
    if err := run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

In this case it is using *MyError and &MyError, but I try to remove the * and & and it works correctly. Why are they using pointers in this example? What is the difference with normal variables? When should I use pointers or not?

Answer (score 3):

"When should I use pointers?" is a very large question without a simple answer. Pointers are a way of passing a reference to a value, rather than a value itself, around, allowing you to modify the original value or "see" modifications to that value. It also prevents copying, which can be a performance improvement in very limited circumstances (do not pass pointers around all the time because it *might* be a performance improvement). Finally, pointers also let you represent "nothingness", which each pointer being able to be `nil`. This is both a blessing and a curse as you must check if each pointer is `nil` before accessing it, though.

In your specific example, the reason why returning `&MyError` works is because your `Error()` function operates on a value of `*MyError` (a pointer to `MyError`), rather than on a value of `MyError` itself. This means that `*MyError` implements the `Error` interface and is thus assignable to the `error` type, and so it can be returned from any function that expects an `error` as a return value.

Returning `MyError` wouldn't work on its own because `MyError` is not a `*MyError`. Go does some helpful things when dealing with function receivers: It will let you call any method on a `MyError` or `*MyError` if the receiver is `*MyError`, but it will *only* let you call methods on a `*MyError` if the type is `*MyError` - That is, Go will not "create" a pointer for you out of thin air.

If you were to remove `*` from `func (e* MyError)`, you would be telling Go that `Error()` works on any instance of a `MyError`, which means that both `*MyError` and `MyError` would fulfill that contract. That's why both of the following are valid when you don't use a pointer receiver:

```
func (e MyError) Error() string {}

var _ error = MyError{} // Valid
var _ error = &MyError {}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, using pointers will not make a difference. Here's one way to look at it:

In Go, all variables are passed by value. That means:

```
type T struct {...}

func f(value T) {..}

f(t)
```

Above, `t` is passed as value. That means when `f` is called, the compiler creates a copy of `t` and passed that to `f`. Any modifications `f` makes to that copy will not affect the `t` used to call `f`.

If you use pointers:

```
func f(value *T) {...}

f(&t)
```

Above, the compiler will create a pointer pointing to `t`, and pass a copy of that to `f`. If `f` makes changes to `value`, those changes will be made on the instance of `t` used to call `f`. In other words:

```
type T struct {
  x int
}

func f(value T) {
   value.x=1
}

func main() {
   t:=T{}
   f(t)
   fmt.Println(t.x)
}
```

This will print 0, because the modifications made by `f` is done on a copy of `t`.

```
func f(value *T) {
   value.x=1
}

func main() {
   t:=T{}
   f(&t)
   fmt.Println(t.x)
}
```

Above, it will print 1, because the call to `f` changes `t`.

Same idea applies to methods and receivers:

```
type T struct {
   x int
}

func (t T) f() {
   t.x=1
}

func main() {
   t:=T{}
   t.f()
   fmt.Println(t.x)
}
```

Above program will print 0, because the method modifies a copy of `t`.

```
func (t *T) f() {
   t.x=1
}

func main() {
   t:=T{}
   t.f()
   fmt.Println(t.x)
}
```

Above program will print 1, because the receiver of the method is declared with a pointer, and calling `t.f()` is equivalent to `f(&t)`.

So, use pointers when passing arguments or when declaring methods if you want to modify the object, or if copying the object would be too expensive.

This is only a small part of the story about pointer arguments.